# How to generate the Json format request using c# in VS?

Tags: c#, json.net

Here is my method to generate the JSON formatter I'm using the SerializeObject json converter in code... But i'm stuck in adding the header value like shipper, destination & other headers here...

```
    string json = @"{
                        'Shipper': {        
                      }
                    }";




JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

            JObject Shipper = (JObject)rss["Shipper"];
            Shipper.Add("AddressId", ShipperAddressId);
            Shipper.Add("ShipperReference", ShipperReference);
            Shipper.Add("ShipperDepartment", ShipperDepartment);
            Shipper.Add("CompanyName", ShipperCompanyName);
            Shipper.Add("ContactName", ShipperContactName);
            Shipper.Add("AddressLine1", ShipperAddressLine1);
            Shipper.Add("AddressLine2", ShipperAddressLine2);
            Shipper.Add("AddressLine3", ShipperAddressLine3);
            Shipper.Add("Town", ShipperTown);
            Shipper.Add("County", ShipperCounty);
            Shipper.Add("CountryCode", ShipperCountryCode);
            Shipper.Add("Postcode", ShipperPostcode);
            Shipper.Add("PhoneNumber", ShipperPhoneNumber);
            Shipper.Add("EmailAddress", ShipperEmailAddress);
            Shipper.Add("VatNumber", ShipperVatNumber);


            json = rss.ToString();
            JObject jsonTxt = JObject.Parse(json);
            string jsonreq = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonTxt, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

output I'm getting as :

```
{
  "Shipper": {
    "AddressId": "",
    "ShipperReference": "Ref14",
    "ShipperDepartment": "",
    "CompanyName": "Intersoft Test Company",
    "ContactName": "Intersoft ",
    "AddressLine1": "Blays House",
    "AddressLine2": "Englefield Green",
    "AddressLine3": "Wick Road",
    "Town": "Egham",
    "County": "Surrey",
    "CountryCode": "GB",
    "Postcode": "TW20 0HJ",
    "PhoneNumber": "7894561252",
    "EmailAddress": "",
    "VatNumber": ""
  }
}
```

But my actual output should be like below format:

```
{
"Shipper": 
{
"AddressId": "",
"ShipperReference": "",
"ShipperDepartment": "",
"CompanyName": "",
"ContactName": "Jane Smith",
"AddressLine1": "Level 5",
"AddressLine2": "Hashmoore House",
"AddressLine3": "10 Sky Lane",
"Town": "Leatherhead",
"County": "Surrey",
"CountryCode": "",
"Postcode": "",
"PhoneNumber": "07723456789",
"EmailAddress": "email@server.com",
"VatNumber": ""
},
"Destination": 
{
"AddressId": "",
"CompanyName": "",
"ContactName": "",
"AddressLine1": "",
"AddressLine2": "10 Round Road",
"AddressLine3": "Mitre Peak",
"Town": "Leatherhead",
"County": "Surrey",
"CountryCode": "",
"Postcode": "",
"PhoneNumber": "",
"EmailAddress": "email@example.com",
"VatNumber": ""
},
"ShipmentInformation": 

{
"ShipmentDate": "2020-03-04",
"ServiceCode": "",
"ServiceOptions": {
"PostingLocation": "",
        "ServiceLevel": "01",
      "ServiceFormat": "",
      "Safeplace": "",
      "SaturdayGuaranteed": false,
      "ConsequentialLoss": "",
      "LocalCollect": false,
      "TrackingNotifications": "",
      "RecordedSignedFor": ""
     },
"TotalPackages": 1,
"TotalWeight": 0.75,
"WeightUnitOfMeasure": "KG",
"Product": "NDX",
"DescriptionOfGoods": "Clothing",
"ReasonForExport": "",
"Value": 100,
"Currency": "GBP",
"LabelFormat": "ZPL300DPI",
"SilentPrintProfile": "",
"ShipmentAction": "process",
"Packages": 

[

{
"PackageOccurrence": 1,
"PackagingId": "",
"Weight": 0.75,
"Length": 15,
"Width": 15,
"Height": 15
}
],
"Items": 

[

{
"ItemId": "",
"Quantity": 1,
"Description": "White Tee-shirt",
"Value": 100,
"Weight": 0.75,
"PackageOccurrence": 1,
"HsCode": "",
"SkuCode": "",
"CountryOfOrigin": "",
"ImageUrl": ""
}
]
}
}
```

But my issue is have to add the Destination , ShipmentInformation headers too....
I'm new to this json converter.... I hope you will be able to help me,

Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: View Json as the serialisation of an object. Use Visual studio special paste(in the top menu bar). And generate the class that will generate the right serialisation. Initialise and populate the elment and the serialisation will be fixed^^

Comment: If you have a hard time finding the menu copy past your expected Json into http://json2csharp.com. It will give you the same classes. the rest is simple object declaration and initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your Expected Json into something like json2csharp as suggested.  It will automatically generate the classes you need for serialization.  That site is very helpful but you wanna make sure your Expected Json is in the finalized format.

Once it generates those classes, add those classes to your project.

Then you would need to populate your classes with data for instance base on your json and what i pasted into the site it created a RootObject with subclasses:

```
RootObject myJsonRoot = new RootObject();
myJsonRoot.Shipper = new Shipper(); //Or if you have a populated shipper class you can set it equal to that without having to fill the properties out one by one.
myJsonRoot.Shipper.AddressId = ShipperAddressId;
//Fill out Remaining Shipper Properties 
myJsonRoot.Destination = new Destination();
myJsonRoot.Destination.AddressLine2 = ShipperAddressLine2;
//Fill out Remaining Destination and other classes Properties

//From here once your RootObject is fully populated you can call JsonConvert.Serialize
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJsonRoot);
```

Now you have your expected Json in the output variable and do with it what you will.

Comment: Hi @Bearcat9425...., Thanks :).... My issue got resolved... & got the response as expected... while validating the response i'm facing one issue....

```
"Packages": [
        {
            "PackageOccurance": 1,
            "UniqueId": "3A0069786000000104A37",
            "TrackingUrl": "https://www.ABC.DEF/track-your-item#/tracking-results/3A0069786000000104A37",
            "CarrierCode": "XXX"
        }
    ]
```
Where i need to get this response property alone...for ex: PackageOccurance, UniqueID, TrackingUrl ...etc... 

Hope your reply will be more helpful to me

Comment: Without knowing the expected Response format its really hard to give guidance on how to extract that data you are looking.  My Suggestion would be to take your entire JSON response and do the same thing as you did with your post data.  Paste the response into json2csharp, get the necessary classes added to your project but instead of serialize, you would deserialize your response into the newly created classes.   Something like  ResponseRootObject myResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseRootObject>(json);